# Open URL from button Dashcode

Tags: xcode, url, web-applications, dashcode

I am sure that this is extremely easy and probably a one liner but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I am creating a very simple web app in Dashcode (my first time) that has a button, when you press it, it needs to link to a url.

Cannot seem to find anything.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being what I needed:

```
document.location = ("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

I relied on [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MakingaWidgetwithDashcode/MakingaWidgetwithDashcode.html) for this:

```
function yourHandler(event) {
     widget.openURL("http://store.apple.com/");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this...  First add button event onclick (openURL)  Then code follows...

```
function openURL()
{
  if ( window.widget )
  {
    widget.openURL( “http://www.google.com” );
    return false;
  }
}
```

Or Try...

```
{
 widget.openURL('http://www.google.com');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too

```
function myButtonPressHandler(event)
{
  var websiteURL = "http://www.google.com";
  location = websiteURL;
}
```